How to take care of holes in shower walls
I just bought a condo from a woman who'd installed shower bars in both her master bedroom shower (shower walls made of some kind of stone, it appears) and in her guest bathroom. It was easy enough to unscrew them and take them out, but now I have drill bit-size holes in both shower walls. What's the best material to fill them with, as I don't want water from the showers to get behind the shower walls? Thanks!

I prefer polyurethane caulk. I have seen other that used grout with a sealer over when dry, or silicone caulk.
